# Linux log grows large, resets, does it again

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, syslog

Am running Ubuntu 18 and don't have a ton on their for apps. The hardware is setup with one 120gb SSD as root/boot and the rest of the drives as 2 pair of raid drives where media files, etc... reside.

I have read, googled, experimented, etc... to figure why I can somehow clean the space at almost 65gb for log files in `/var/log/` only in 2 more days for it to hit that again. Googled things like [this](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS815US815&q=how%20to%20clear%20var%20log%20messages%20in%20linux&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL146T7PHfAhVO7lQKHab7DGMQ1QIoAXoECAUQAg&biw=1829&bih=888) to setting up logrotate to minimze and compress.

Have tried via command line, GUI, etc.. to see what is going on. Once it is full, I cannot even run gnome on it. For the most part, this server simple hosts some code repos that arent very active, plex media, calibre, with a webmin interface. Have uninstalled other things in order to figure out the root of this problem.

Really hoping to get some help, feedback, etc... to put this behind me.

Thanks much.

Comment: Large logs are usually only a symptom of real problems. You should fix the root cause. See what the largest logs contain, so you know which processes require your attention.

Comment: To see the last X lines of a logfile, open a terminal wonfow and run sudo tail -X /path/to/log.file | less - where X is the number of lines, and sudo us only neccessary if the gile cant be reaf by your user. Ehich file is growing very quickly?

Comment: There's 65 gigs of *compressed* logfiles created every 2 days? What are the biggest logfiles called, what's in them? Is the filesystem clean, it's not just reporting a file as gigantic when it's really not, or getting the free space count wrong?

Comment: So my issue seems like this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1772677 . Not sure how to fix, but can clear the syslog. Did some searching and not finding a fix. Am I missing something? Can someone help?